# Change existing project version control system

Tags: git, tfs, project

TFS2012 allows users to create projects that use either Team Foundation Version Control or Git as Version Control systems.

I'd like to know if there's any way to change an existing TFS2012 project version control system from Team Foundation Version Control to Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

According to [Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx#10389636) this is not supported.

> no, you can't convert in place, but you can use Git-TF to pull from TFVC and push to a project with a Git  repo and keep history.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this link http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/01/31/move-a-tfservice-source-control-to-tf-service-git-based-team-project/

Here we can see how to use Git-TF to do that.